# Setting the active slide in swiper/react with react state

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I would like to ask if there is a way to control/set the active slide with swiper/react?

I have tried to handle the onSwiper function with props but still cant update the slide index.

Thank you

Comment: Hi please include what you have tried.

Answer (score 25):

You can use swiper instance to access swiper API (https://swiperjs.com/api/)
and there is method `slideTo`.

So in code example it can looks like this

```
const App = () => {
  // store swiper instance
  const [swiper, setSwiper] = useState(null);

  const slideTo = (index) => swiper.slideTo(index);

  return (
      <Swiper onSwiper={setSwiper} >
        {/* ... */}
      </Swiper>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Im getting
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'slideTo' of null`. Maybe 
im missing something in my implementation.

```const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null)
const slideTo = index => thumbsSwiper.slideTo(index)

React.useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    slideTo(4)
  }, 2000)
}, [])
```

Comment: When i console.log(swiper) it is returning null.

Comment: @CarloCarpio it's because at start the init value of state is `null`, and then after some time is swiper initialized, but useEffect doesn't react on that change... please see working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-test-p67q8?file=/index.js

Comment: @CarloCarpio please accept this answer if it has solved your problem

Comment: I suggest adding this in `slideTo` to prevent a couple of common errors, e.g.


const slideTo = (index) => {
    if (!swiper || swiper.destroyed) {
      return;
    }

    swiper.slideTo(index);
};

Answer (score 1):

just use this

```
const App = () => {
 
  const [swiper, setSwiper] = useState(null);

  const slideTo = (index) => {
if(swiper) 
swiper.slideTo(index)};

  return (
      <Swiper onSwiper={setSwiper} >
        {/* ... */}
      </Swiper>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useSwiper` to get the swiper instance inside Swiper on React, and then freely control behaviors of the Swiper including using `slideTo` method.

Like:

```
import { Swiper, useSwiper } from 'swiper/react'

const SomethingInsideSwiper = () => {
  const swiper = useSwiper()

  // on click
  const handleOnSetSwiper = () => {
    swiper.slideTo(/* index */)
  }

  // or use side effect
  useEffect(() => {
    swiper.slideTo(/* index */)
  }, /* [state] if you need controlled by a state */)

  return (<>{/* ...... /*}</>)
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Swiper {/* SwiperProps */} >
      <SomethingInsideSwiper />
    </Swiper>
  )
}
```

Comment: what version is this?

Comment: In 2022, so it may be 8

Answer (score 1):

The newer option is to set `initialSlide={specificIndex}` on `<Swiper>` instance.
If you know which index you want to slide to, just set "initialSlide" prop for Swiper.

Like here:

```
<Swiper initialSlide={clickedIndex}>

    <SwiperSlide>
        Slide content 1
    </SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>
        Slide content 2
    </SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>
        Slide content 3
    </SwiperSlide>

</Swiper>
```

I test this only in React 17.

Comment: this sets an INITIAL slide but then it does not change depending on state/index changes. How can I get this to work?

Comment: @RobertO'Toole, yes this implementation set the initial slide. The initial slide shouldn't be changed when you are using that slider. Can you explain your use-case, so I understand your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a component to do just that (change slide) and stuff it inside (this is important)  component.

```
   const ChangeSlide = ({ position }) => {
      const swiper = useSwiper()

      useEffect(() => {
         if (swiper) {
            swiper.slideTo(position)
         }
      }, [swiper, position])
      return null
   }
```

then stuff it inside `<Swipe>` component:

```
<Swiper ...>
   <ChangeSlide position={2} />
   <Swiperlide> ... </SwiperSlide>
   <Swiperlide> ... </SwiperSlide>
   <Swiperlide> ... </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```